# .Net c# webbrowser fill input without id or classname

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, browser

I need to fill an input in webbrowser but this doesn't work. I think it has to be done with name property but how?

```
foreach (HtmlElement login in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
{
     if (login.GetAttribute("name") == "username")
     {
        login.SetAttribute("value", "xyz");

     }
 }
```

For this data:

```
<input class="lfFieldInput" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" 
autocapitalize="false" autocorrect="false" value="" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1">
```

But code is not filling the data (xyz).

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with the code you have posted?

Comment: Is the condition hit?

Comment: @BenRobinson the code is not filling the data (xyz).

Comment: @digiogi i think he got that ;). But does your code even reach the if?

Comment: @Koen No, it doesn't :(

Comment: Code looks ok, put a breakpoint before entering the IF statement and tell us what you see for Login... k?

Comment: This is on instagram login page. https://instagram.com/accounts/login/ 
Is it possible that it won't work because of ajax stuff?

Comment: Are you sure that this element is not nested somewhere ? :)

Comment: It is nested under divs and labels etc. instagram.com/accounts/login  page.

Comment: it could be that input element can be inside one of nested frame

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following way:

```
IHTMLElementCollection inputElements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")

foreach (HtmlElement login in inputElements)
{
   if (login.GetAttribute("name") == "username")
   {
      login.SetAttribute("value", "xyz");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this work

```
HtmlElementCollection col = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement element in col)
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute("name").Equals("username"))
            {                   
                element.SetAttribute("value", "xyz");
            }
         }
```